# Making the English tags synonym to the corresponding Hebrew ones

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think it might be nice if these are made synonyms. For example:

- Heaven -> Gan Eden
- Hell -> Gehinam
- Hereafter/Afterlife -> Ha-'Olam Ha-Ba

etc.

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone's *using* a tag, I don't see the real need for it to be made a synonym of an existing tag. I agree that where both tags are being used they should be made synonyms.

Comment: Usually I would agree with this - however, in J.SE's case, translation is a real issue. Moreover, there are many tags that already contain both (not to mention some transliterations and alternate spellings...) - these should be split accordingly.

Comment: @AviD: I've now added synonyms to the `shabbat` tag from a bunch of its common transliterations and translations. What do you think?

Comment: I think thats great, thanks (but I have to ask about some of them, if they're really used...!) Now to slowly expand to other tags...